# Standalone configuration file for serilog

Tags: serilog

I'm looking for a way to provide a standalone XML/JSON configuration file for serilog which is dynamicaly loaded from the directory the application itself runs in.

I'm looking for something similiar to what [NLog provides](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading). As described in [Nlog#Configuration-file](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#file-locations):

> For a stand-alone *.exe application, files are searched as follows:
>
> - standard application configuration file (usually applicationname.exe.config)
> - applicationname.exe.nlog in application’s directory
> - **NLog.config in application’s directory (Name sensitive; using docker dotnet core)**
> - NLog.dll.nlog in a directory where NLog.dll is located (only if NLog isn't installed in the GAC)

Is there any similar behaviour in serilog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself in this [wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration).

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("debug.json")
    .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Where `debug.json` is a file in the application directory which can be changed. My sample file looks like

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "log.log" } }
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```